# Why android alarm triggers (plays sound) while the time is set to backward?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

**The problem with my alarm clock is it plays alarm ring even I set the time backward.**

The alarm mainly starts when a user toggle the switch.

**Another problem with that is toggling the switch *OFF* doesn't stop the alarm. And it only happens while alarm triggering at the idle of the device or app. That means when the device is idle and alarm triggers, I have to open the alarmClock app to switch off the alarm, at that time pressing the toggle switch doesn't stop the sound.**

In another situation other than triggering alarm at idle of the device the alarm clock works fine and I can toggle the button to stop the alarm.

Please help me with those issue.

MainActivity:

```
package com.mycompany.alarmclock;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;//an action to be performed by other/foreign application
    private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;//In where the user set the time
    private static MainActivity inst;
    private TextView alarmTextView;//the area where alarm message/notification will be displayed


    public static MainActivity instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
        alarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
        ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }


    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {//if toggle button is "ON" do the alarming function
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm On");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        } else {
            AlarmReceiver.stopRingtone();
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            setAlarmText("");
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
        }

    }

    public void setAlarmText(String alarmText) {
        alarmTextView.setText(alarmText);

    }
}
```

Alarmreceiver:

```
package com.mycompany.alarmclock;

import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

import java.net.URI;

public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static Ringtone mRingtone=null;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        MainActivity inst=MainActivity.instance();
        inst.setAlarmText("\n                  Alarm!\n           Get Up! Get up!");
        Uri alarmUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        mRingtone=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,alarmUri);
        mRingtone.play();
        //ringtone.play();

        //this will send a notification message
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
    public  static void stopRingtone(){
        mRingtone.stop();
    }
}
```

AlarmService:

```
    package com.mycompany.alarmclock;

import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

private NotificationManager alarmnotificationManager;

    public AlarmService(){
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sendNotification("Get up! Get up!");

    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg){

        Log.d("AlarmService","Sending notification...:"+msg);
        alarmnotificationManager=(NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);


        alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        alarmnotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs for `set()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately.

[Sources of Android alarm clock](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock) may be useful also.

Comment: Sergey Glotov,thank you for your quick look! In fact I haven't used that method. Besides, it's not good, because no user wants their alarm triggers at past time! Ok, can you please look on my second problem?

Comment: I see `alarmManager.set()` in your code. Didn't you use it?

Comment: Ahh u meant that? ya sorry! here is it: alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); i used it. is there any alternative method to avoid this irritating thing (triggering alarm in past time)? However, my important concentration is on my second problem now.

Comment: about the second part: try to move ringtone stuff to the service.

Comment: the whole onReceive method?

Comment: `onReceive()` should be in the receiver :) Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)? Receiver should start the service, service should do the work.

Comment: [How it is done in the system alarm clock](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock/blob/master/src/com/android/alarmclock/AlarmKlaxon.java)